# Laravel ordering a eloquent call, orderBy()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this line

```
$entries = $company->sheet_entries->where('date', $this->getToday())->take(5);
```

I would like to order by 'date','desc'

Once would assume that would be done like this.

```
$entries = $company->sheet_entries->where('date', $this->getToday())->orderBy('date','desc')->take(5);
```

But that returns a error

```
Method orderBy does not exist.
```

I've used orderBy before when calling eloquent but with brakets; for example I have line below that works:

```
$last = $user->sheet_entries()->where('company_id', $user->company_privileges->company_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

What is the difference any why wont the second example work?

Answer (score 1):

```
dd($entries = $company->sheet_entries()->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->take(5)->get());
```

works!

I still don't understand the difference between using *$company->* and *$company()->* so any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: If you access a relationship as a property like `->sheet_entries` the model will fetch the entries and return a `Collection` instance, so you can't extend that query with `orderBy`, since it was already run on the database. When you access a relationship as a method like `->sheet_entries()`, the model will return a Query Builder instance that allows you to add stuff to your query, like `orderBy` and anything else the builder offers. This functionality is achieved internally via `__get` and `__call` [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.magic.php).